# javascript amendment if within an if

Tags: javascript

I've never used javascript before and just need a bit of help.  I have this:

```
if (vars.devUrl != '')
{     
  vars.smsmessage = vars.smsmessage + "\n\n" + vars.devUrl + "\n\n" +     vars.optOut;
}
else
{
   vars.smsmessage = vars.smsmessage + "\n\n" + vars.optOut;
}
delivery.smsParameters.smsContent = vars.smsmessage;
```

But I need to amend it to say if the vars.smsmessage includes the string "http:" then suppress the vars.devUrl

I've come up with the below, would an if in an if work?

```
if (vars.devUrl != '')
{
    if (vars.smsmessage includes("http:"))
    {
        vars.smsmessage = vars.smsmessage + "\n\n" + vars.optOut;
    }  
    else
    {
        vars.smsmessage = vars.smsmessage + "\n\n" + vars.devUrl + "\n\n" + vars.optOut;
    }
else
{
    vars.smsmessage = vars.smsmessage + "\n\n" + vars.optOut;
}
}
delivery.smsParameters.smsContent = vars.smsmessage;
```

Also should add that I can't test this before I go live very easily at all, hence the request

Comment: `would an if in an if work` - Certainly. Why don't you try that? But `includes` will not work. You might have to use `indexOf`

Answer (score 2):

Very close, but the `else` comes outside the `if` block, and you need to use `indexOf` in Javascript to check if one string contains another, like so:

```
if (vars.devUrl) {
    if (vars.smsmessage.indexOf('http:') > -1) {
        vars.smsmessage = vars.smsmessage + '\n\n' + vars.optOut;
    }  
    else {
        vars.smsmessage = vars.smsmessage + '\n\n' + vars.devUrl + '\n\n' + vars.optOut;
    }
}
else {
    vars.smsmessage = vars.smsmessage + '\n\n' + vars.optOut;
}

delivery.smsParameters.smsContent = vars.smsmessage;
```

However, you can make this a little easier on the eye using a [ternary conditional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) like so:

```
    var url = vars.smsmessage.indexOf('http:') > -1 ? vars.devUrl + '\n\n' : '';

    vars.smsmessage += '\n\n' + url + vars.optout;

    delivery.smsParameters.smsContent = vars.smsmessage;
```

Comment: Although I like your second approach and would certainly do it like you,  `+=` and ternary operator are to my opinion much harder for a beginner (as the OP seems to be) so your solution might look very complicated to the OP. Your first approach on the other hand repeats some code while it could be avoided (cfr my answer)

Comment: The first "example" was just a copy-paste of his code with a couple changes, not meant to be perfect.  And although I understand what you're saying, I think that it's *more* important for beginners to be exposed to things like ternary operators and `+=` - which aren't that "advanced" at all.  I wouldn't provide a beginner an example using promises.. but ternary is simple and `+=` is even simpler.

Comment: They're not "advanced", they're just notation shortcuts and don't offer any performance improvements while making code reading much more complicated for a beginner as you need to know/understand this extra syntax... So definitely +1 for the didactic approach and the somewhat elegant proposition, but still I would prefer if your first example was more of a best-practice without repeating code bits... which is why I answered myself.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, for this specific request your intial code don't need and extra `if`, simply an extra condition :

```
if (vars.devUrl != '' && vars.devUrl.indexOf('http:') < 0)
{     
  vars.smsmessage = vars.smsmessage + "\n\n" + vars.devUrl + "\n\n" +     vars.optOut;
}
else
{
   vars.smsmessage = vars.smsmessage + "\n\n" + vars.optOut;
}
delivery.smsParameters.smsContent = vars.smsmessage;
```

So; basically, you use vars.devUrl only if it's not empty AND if it doesn't contain "http:"